# Finding the reason for duplication in mqtt persistence

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

We have been using a publisher-subscriber with QOS 1 to check Persistence. We have a lot of duplication happening for the published messages in the mosquitto.db file (5-7 times). We are unable to understand the reason for such huge duplication. Any inputs on the same would be appreciable.

The reason we are bothered about duplication is that broker is unable to handle the huge loads and shuts down while pushing it to a reconnected subscriber.

Say I have P1 pushing around 1k messages/second to a broker and S1 subscribing for those. We shut down S1 for a while say, 1 hr and reconnected again with the same client id.

Now, ideally, we should have around 1k*60*60 messages in my db file. However, we found out that it has more than 5-7 times of the number. Once I start subscribing, the r/w is huge and hence the server shuts down my broker.

QOS 2 is our worst case option, so would be grateful for other alternatives.

Here are the configurations :

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
max_inflight_messages 1

persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
allow_anonymous false
max_queued_messages 1000000

autosave_interval 30
# autosave_on_changes false
```

Answer (score 0):

The entries in the persistence db will be based on the number of subscribers to the topic as the messages need to be tracked/queued for each subscriber that may be offline or hasn't acknowledged the receipt of the message yet.

Given the message rates you are talking about (especially if you are queuing and want QOS1/2 level delivery), you might want to look at a broker that handles persistence out of band (Something multithreaded with a external db backend). The situation you describe would mean 3.6million message that need to be delivered on reconnect as well as trying to keep up with the 1k/s message (which is likely to mean more queuing as they back up)

If you can't/don't want to change the broker to something multithreaded then, you've not mentioned what sort of filesystem you are storing the persistence db on? Have you tried looking at using a RAM disk to improve the access time as it would all be in memory?